# How I can resolve this issue?

Tags: css, sass

I have a little issue with my SCSS code. I'm tired to put a card behind other, but just stack in the bottom of the parent container, I was trying to invert position parent from relative to absolute but isn't work I'm really stuck here.

```css
.card {
  perspective: 150rem;
  -moz-perspective: 150rem;
  position: relative;
  height: 50rem;
  &__side {
    color: $color-white;
    font-size: 2rem;
    height: 50rem;
    transition: all .8s ease;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1.5rem 4rem rgba($color-black, $alpha: .15);
    &--front {
      background-color: $color-white;
    }
    &--back {
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
      &-1 {
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, $color-secundary-light, $color-primary-light);
      }
    }
  }
  &:hover &__side--front {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  &:hover &__side--back {
    transform: rotateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1-of-3">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__side card__side--front"> Front </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__side card__side--back card__side--back-1"> Back </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please provide [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), e.g. some HTML wouldn't hurt or a link to a code sandbox showing the issue.

Comment: This HTML code for the cards:

  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-1-of-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card__side card__side--front">
                                Front
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card">
                        <div class="card__side card__side--back card__side--back-1">
                            Back
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>

 
                </div>